# Symfony: Organising multi-client application’s business logic

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, directory-structure

Problem:
I’m unsure how to set up multi client application for Symfony so that we would not violate Symfony's best practices and work against the framework.
I would like to have one main Core namespace which would contain all the base model classes. Right next to the core I would like to set up client specific namespaces which would be used, based on client regional setting. For example LocalUS for US market, LocalUK, for UK market etc.
The Local* namespaces should take first priority for including twig templates, and as a fallback use core common shared views (as I understand, this is solvable via twig namespaces). Same goes for controllers and models - these are probably solvable via extending the Core namespaced classes? Is this all solvable via routing and providing paths for these Local* controllers?
I was looking up on github to see if there are any project that have similar setup but I couldn’t find anything.

A little background:
We have an older legacy PHP Application which was built in-house from ground up using plain PHP. As the application has grown over time, it has become hard to maintain good code quality and standards. It’s also very time consuming to teach new developers our application logic, since the application basically follows no standard design patterns and just does it’s own thing. A lot of the underlying code which handles routes, controllers etc seems to work like “magic” that nobody really dares to touch.

It is because of that we would like to migrate our application to Symfony3 framework. I’ve read some articles about the overall process of migrating legacy applications to symfony, and managed to do it with silex pretty well. Silex, however is a bit too lightweight, I found that the assetic service provider had a lot of functionality missing (twig namespacing etc), and decided it would be best if we could move to a full stack symfony framework instead.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [Symfony bundles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/bundles.html) - they do exactly what you need. You create a "base" bundle, than extend it with other bundles. That's how FOSUserBundle works - it provides everything you need, than you extend it and overwrite it.